# How to extract points from clusplot graph?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I’m trying to extract the points (IDs) that occur in both ellipses from the graph produced by the function clusplot below.

```
    library(cluster)
    # Creates a sample data set.
    y <- matrix(runif(5000,max=1,min=0), 1000, 5, dimnames=list(paste("g", 1:1000, sep=""), paste("t", 1:5, sep=""))) 
    kc <- kmeans(y, centers=2)
    # plot kmeans clusters
    clusplot(y, kc$cluster, color=TRUE, shade=TRUE,labels=4, lines=0)
```

[image]

Comment: A crude way would be to extract `z` object from `clusplot.default` result and convert it to `sp` objects of `SpatialPolygon` and make a  `SpatialPoints` object from `s.x.2d` and use some geometry magic from `rgeos` package to infer points.

Comment: hmmm. they are not supposed to be ellipses at all. But have a look at the `kc` object!

Comment: 'kc$cluster' has k clusters (k=2), each row (ID) belong's to a single cluster. 'clustplot' has a nice visualization (ellipses) and not kc.